# getting React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase to handle my login/register form, however, I have imported the AuthProvider from AuthContext, but I go to my broweser, the page is blank and in the console i see the below error message[image: React.jsx error]

I have to search around but nothing seemed to have solved the issue,
could anyone please help me with this?

here is my code

App.js

```
mport "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./Profile";
import Register from "./Register";
import VerifyEmail from "./VerifyEmail";
import Login from "./Login";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AuthProvider } from "./AuthContext";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

function App() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthProvider value={{ currentUser }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Profile} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/verify-email" component={VerifyEmail} />
        </Switch>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: As the error mentions, the most likely cause is an improper import. Check to make sure that Profile, Register, VerifyEmail, and Login are all using default exports, not named exports, and that AuthProvider is using a named export, not a default export.

Comment: all are using export default except for the AuthProvdider....

import React, {useContext} from 'react'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function AuthProvider({children, value}) {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function useAuthValue(){
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}